# select statement for sum of column value in db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, cumulative-sum

I have this data in db2 which I need a query for...

```
location | part | quantity
--------------------------
  loc1     TD3     300
  loc1     RA5      0
  loc1     BC4     200
  loc2     MO2      4
  loc2     CY1      0
  loc4     RA5     100
  loc4     PL5     400
  loc3     YT7      2
  loc3     UA9      5
```

The result set would return the `'location's` which have a sum of their `'quantity'` of less than 10. The `'part'` does not matter. So in the case above, I would get this result set.

```
location | total quantity
-------------------------
  loc2          4
  loc3          7
```

This needs to be a sql query for the database **db2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want "cumulative quantity", you just want the sum:

```
select location, sum(quantity)
from db2
group by location
having sum(quantity) < 10;
```

"cumulative" would imply a running sum or cumulative sum.